# Open HTM page on a new window on a Silverlight project

Tags: html, silverlight

On my Silverlight project I have created an HTM page where I included an Iframe tag.

I want to open this page on a new browser tab. This is what I have trying to implement on a button click event:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new System.Uri("../Forms/Page.htm", System.UriKind.Relative), "_blank");

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new System.Uri("../Forms/Page.htm", "_blank");

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new System.Uri("/Forms/Page.htm", "_blank");

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new System.Uri("Page.htm", "_blank");
```

So far none of this approaches worked. I keep getting 404 error saying that page was not found.

Is there anyway to work around this issue?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Your page must be in the **web** project.
If page is located at the project's root, this works (anywhere in solution):

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new System.Uri("/page.htm", UriKind.Relative), "_blank");
```

If your page is inside silverlight application project, you can not access it directly by HtmlPage.Window.Navigate, however you can load its content (then for example save it to local folder and finally display it or use WebBrowser as explained [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/06/22/silverlight-html-and-the-webbrowser-control-for-offline-apps.aspx))

```
        var sm = Application.GetResourceStream(new System.Uri("page.htm", UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sm.Stream);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        browser.NavigateToString(content);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up trying another approach and didn't have a chance to test your code. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to open web page in silver light.

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ShowBrowserIFrame", url);
```

ShowBrowserIFrame is JS function, add this function to html page of silver light.

```
function ShowBrowserIFrame(url) {
BrowserDivContainer.css('display', 'block');
$('<iframe id="' + jobPlanIFrameID + '" src="' + url + '" style="height:100%;width:100%;" />')
.appendTo(BrowserDivIFrameContainer);
slHost.css('width', '0%');
}
```

Check this [post](http://webdesignpluscode.blogspot.com.tr/2016/02/how-to-integrate-html-page-in.html) for complete solution.